# Custom Errors Page Not Working With Stats HttpHandler/Global - possible to disable for one page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have written a custom error page that displays an error message. Its an aspx page (and it needs to be).

The problem is that I tested the custom errors with a disabled database and the page just won't load. This is due (I think) to the fact that I have httphandlers and global.asax code trying to access the database so the app can never get to the error.aspx page if the db is down.

Anybody know how to disable all httphandlers and global.asax events from a page within an app?

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you handle your error in Global_Asax and redirect the user to Error.aspx from Application_Error with a proper error message?

Comment: Im not trying to handle the error. Im simply redirecting them to an error page but it wont redirect properly due to the fact that one of my httphandlers cant access the database.

Comment: You can disable the handler from IIS. You can redirect them to your error page as I've told you and it would be better than disabling handlers!

Comment: Hi, this is a peice of software I so cant just disable the handler as we use it for logging/security etc.. :-(